# How to set display name for a React class (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've tried several methods in setting the display name for my React Component, but none has worked:
I tried to set it as a public static variable like this:

```
class Base extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public static displayName = "Base";
    constructor(props){
        ...
    }
    render(){
        ...
    }
}
```

But eslint still throws me this error:

`error    Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name`

I tried an alternative approach where I set it outside the class definition:

```
class Base extends React.Component<any, any>{
    constructor(props){
        ...
    }
    render(){
        ...
    }
}
Base.displayName = "Base";
```

And I end up getting an error saying:

`Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'typeof Base'.`

I've tried different methods from other Stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to get rid of the error. How can I resolve this? Please help.

edit: answered my own question below. The core of this problem seemed to be regarding anonymous functions rather than the React class.

Comment: I don't think this error comes from those examples, please make a producible one: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [*"Usually, you don’t need to set it explicitly because it’s inferred from the name of the function or class that defines the component."*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname)

Comment: Base.name maybe could work?

Comment: @BlackHole That also does not work. Gives the error Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof Base'.

Comment: @avhhh Allright, in javascript you can get the class name with Object methods, but it dont work i dont know

Comment: @BlackHole I actually tried it again since I actually made a typo last time. It says that name is a "Read only property" when I tried to set it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `public static displayName = "Base";` remove public and use it like `static displayName = "Base";`

```
class Base extends React.Component<any, any>{
    static displayName = "Base";
    constructor(props){
        ...
    }
    render(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The eslint gives me two errors after this change:

`Missing accessibility modifier on class property displayName  @typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility`
 and 
`Component definition is missing display name                  react/display-name`

Comment: Disable the rule in `.eslintrc` file

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. It turned out that the problem lies in a different area than I had originally thought. The eslint error `Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name` was indicated where I used an anonymous function to return the React Component:

```
export function renderForm(){
    return {
        react: () => <Base />
    }
}
```

I thought that it was saying that `<Base/>` needed a displayName, but it turned out that the problem is the unnamed function. I resolved it by naming that function:

```
export function renderForm(){
    return {
        react: function renderComponent(){ return <Base />}
    }
}
```

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but the eslint error is now gone!

edit: changing the rule, as mentioned from the other two answers is also a valid solution fyi

Comment: Also was misleading by this rule, after named function or assigning it to variable this error gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [this ESLint plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md) I take it?

In that case, did you set `ignoreTranspilerName` option to `true`? If so, that could be your issue.

Why even have this rule if you already have  names for your component? The transpiler should use the class name as the component name by default

Comment: I'm still really new at this, but where would you set this rule change?

Comment: Your .eslintrc file, see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring